# how to print Scala user defined Arrays

Tags: arrays, scala

I tried below code but it ultimately prints 5 zeros after giving the user defined values to array .

the below code takes array of size 5 and gives user defined values

```
object printarray {    
  def main(args:Array[String]) {
    val arr = new Array[Int](5)

    println("the values of array is ")
    for(i<-0 to 4) {
      val arr = scala.io.StdIn.readInt()
    }

    arr.foreach(println)
  }
}
```

Comment: You are creating a new `val arr`, inside the `for` expression, that is separate from the one created outside of the `for` expression.

Comment: The actual question is not "how to print" but rather "how to read input into an array".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of things that need improvement in the code.

You allocate an array of 5 elements named `arr` in the scope of the `main` method, but you also declare an additional value with the same name, `arr`, inside the for comprehension scope and read an `Int` into it, which you discard once you exit the for scope. Then, you print the array in the outer scope, which hasn't changed at all.

The first thing you need to make this work, is index into the array instead of creating a new value named `arr` in the inner scope:

```
object printarray {    
  def main(args:Array[String]) {
    val arr = new Array[Int](5)

    println("the values of array is ")
    for (i <- 0 to 4) {
      arr(i) = scala.io.StdIn.readInt()
    }

    arr.foreach(println)
  }
}
```

To improve things further, you use the `yield` Scala synax to make this more concise:

```
val arr = for (i <- 0 to 4) yield StdIn.readInt()
```

This will not return an `Array[Int]`, but an `IndexedSeq[Int]` with an underlying type of `Vector[Int]`. If you still want an `Array[Int]`, you'll have to explicitly call `toArray`:

```
val arr: Array[Int] = (for (i <- 0 to 4) yield scala.io.StdIn.readInt()).toArray
```

Answer (score 2):

In your for-loop you are reassigning the variable in every iteration. You can change it to:

```
for(i <- 0 to 4) {
  arr(i) = scala.io.StdIn.readInt()
}
```

As a side-note, instead of declaring the `arr` before the loop you can simply do:

```
val arr = for(i <- 0 to 4) yield scala.io.StdIn.readInt()
```